# Not able to authenticate with Client credentials

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm new to Autodesk, currently on the free trial. I'm not being able to authenticate my server-to-server app.

Here's my api call:

```bash
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token'  -X 'POST'  
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  
-H 'Accept: application/json'  
-H 'Authorization: Basic *my ClientID:Client secret base64*'  
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials'  
-d 'scope=data:read'
```

The error I'm getting is:

```json
Raw response for the API 
Status code 400
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The token request must specify a valid 'grant_type'."}
```

I've double checked the base64 encoded keys and that my app is server-to-server.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Im suspicious of your curl call. If you have multi line are you using `\` at the end of each line?

Comment: Make sure your input to base64 function is in form of `client_id:client_secret`. Apart from this, your curl call is correct.

Comment: Your command is OK, I just tested it. What you can do to further investigate is import this into a tool such as Insomnia or Postman and see if the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments! The body of the request was type form-data, changed that it worked!